# Which of these url for Feeds for the Sitemap should I use?

Tags: sitemap, rss, xml-sitemap

Does it matter which of these I add to my Sitemaps file?

```
http://example.com/?feed=rss 
http://example.com/?feed=rss2
http://example.com/?feed=rdf 
http://example.com/?feed=atom
```

Comment: Richard, were you asking about putting these URLs INTO your sitemap, or using them AS your sitemap? Because Simone's response is dealing with the second case, and that's not how I read what you wrote above. If that's the case, I'll give him the vote, but I'm not currently sure he's even answering your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't, as long as you are using a supported format. I encourage you to use the rss2 or atom formats.

Moreover, because the feed displays only the latest entries, I suggest you to use a sitemap plugin to list all your pages in the sitemap. The [Google XML Sitemaps](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) is a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

None. The sitemap file is for your site's *content*(pages, media, etc.), not the feeds.
You can actually [use a feed-format file](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183668) *as* your sitemap, for that matter, so this would just be kind of redundant.